# $.ajax is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get the fetchFilm methode to work but I can not fix the ajax part in the  method. I'm not getting the output(Finished! or results) at the console. "Test1" is being alerted.

I appreciate any help

index.php

```
<?php

require 'function.php';

if(isset($_POST['q'])){
    connect();
    $film =  get_film_by_title($_POST['q']);


    }

include 'views/index.tmpl.php';
```

index.tmpl.php:

```
<?php
include '_partials/header.php';

?>

<h1>Search films by title:</h1>
<form id="film-selection" action="index.php" method="post">

    <select name="q" id="q">
        <?php
           $alphabet = str_split('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
           foreach ($alphabet as $letter) {
             echo "<option value='$letter'>$letter</option>";
           }
        ?>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Go!</button>
</form>

     <?php if(isset($film)): ?>
        <ul class="film-list">
            <?php
               foreach ($film as $a) {
                 echo " <li data-film_id='{$a->film_id}'> 
                           <a href='film.php?film_id={$a->film_id}'>{$a->title} </a>
                        </li>";
               }
            ?>

        </ul>
     <?php endif; ?>

<?php include '_partials/footer.php'; ?>
```

script.js

```
var Film = {
    init: function(config){
        this.config = config;
        this.bindEvents();

    },

    bindEvents: function(){
        this.config.letterSection.on('change', this.fetchFilm);

    },

    fetchFilm: function(){
      alert('Test1');

      var self = Film;

      $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: self.config.form.serialize(),
        success: function(results){
            console.log('Finished!');
            console.log(results);

        }
      });
    }
};

Film.init({
   letterSection: $('#q'),
   form: $('#film-selection')
});
```

Comment: First, any errors showing in the browser's Inspector.  Just a though ... set a `dataType` ... I ran into this one time and had to set it to text for a post.

Comment: I second @rfornal 's notion - check the console for errors. Maybe have a look at dev tools' Network tab too to see if you see the POST happening, and make sure it comes back with a 200.

Comment: are you add the jquery file reference on your page? I am not able to see that

Comment: No there is no error showing in the browser or at the console I set dataType but i did not help.

Comment: yes i added jquery file reference in the <?php include '_partials/footer.php'; ?>

Comment: you need to add jquery reference before calling jquery function

Comment: jquery file is working because I'm already getting "Test2" alerted.

Comment: when i select the letter 'j', I'm getting the following in the network console  "green 200 GET index.php?q=j localhost html 1.36 KB  ->7ms"

Comment: at some point did you consider adding an error handler and seeing why success isn't firing? Also inspect actual request return body to see if it is what is expected